# Advertise NO-SOLICITING (RFC3865)

Tags: email, smtp, spam, rfc

Does it bring anything to specify the Solicitation class keywords
in Advertise NO-SOLICITING as per [RFC-3865](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3865.txt)?

For instance: `dom.spammer:ADLT,dom.listing:ADV`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Spammers do not care about whether you want their spam or not.

Comment: They're so heartless. :(

Comment: Yes. Poor spammers.

Comment: From my understanding without this option you are allowing "legitimate" advertising companies to send advertisements since your server doesn't instruct otherwise. I was thinking of it as a snail mailbox sticker stating:`No ads please` :) .

Comment: Originally the idea was that having a notice in place would make it possible to sue spammers - in effect an attempt at a technological solution to a social problem. It has not worked.

Comment: It may actually provide feedback to spammers so they can fix their emails to bypass spamfilters. It's the "evil bit" on steroids. This RFC3865 should be deprecated.